# Why is one request hitting multiple routes?

Tags: node.js, express

When i go to the "/" route express sends the file but for some reason the request also prints the "/*" routes console.log and im not sure why. Is this new express functionality?

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 if(JSON.stringify(req.cookies)=="{}"){
    res.cookie('number',1, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
 }
 else{
    res.cookie('number',Number(req.cookies.number)+1, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
 }
 res.sendFile('main.html', {root: __dirname+"/files/html"});                        
});

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {

 console.log("30hrs")
                       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to each of your routes to see exactly what's going on:

```
console.log(req.path);
```

My guess is that you will find that the `/*` route is showing a request for `/favicon.ico` which is something the browser requests to see if your site has an icon to represent pages.  That would be a completely separate request from the `/` request, but something the browser initiates on its own.

For a variety of reasons, routes that you don't have any unique/appropriate content for should send a 404 response as that more accurately informs the browser or network crawlers what's going on.  That includes requests for `/favicon.ico`, `/robots.txt`, etc...